# Problem Starting up Tile Server

Tags: openstreetmap

I'm following the Switch2OSM guide to the tee. I have not had any trouble I couldn't figure out until now. I've typed the following according to instruction:

```bash
sudo mkdir /var/run/renderd

sudo chown username /var/run/renderd

sudo -u username renderd -f -c /usr/local/etc/renderd.conf
```

I get this error:

> renderd[8641]: An error occurred while loading the map layer 'default': Could not create datasource for type: 'shape'  encountered during parsing of layer 'land-low' in Layer at line 48 of '/usr/local/share/maps/style/OSMBright/OSMBright.xml'renderd[8641]: An error occurred while loading the map layer 'default': Could not create datasource for type: 'shape'  encountered during parsing of layer 'land-low' in Layer at line 48 of '/usr/local/share/maps/style/OSMBright/OSMBright.xml'renderd[8641]: An error occurred while loading the map layer 'default': Could not create datasource for type: 'shape'  encountered during parsing of layer 'land-low' in Layer at line 48 of '/usr/local/share/maps/style/OSMBright/OSMBright.xml'

Comment: A famous search engine will return various results for "Could not create datasource for type: 'shape'". Did you already try the corresponding solutions?

Comment: I did yes, Most problems I found were not exactly the same, but I did resolve the issue. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Please tell us how you did resolve your problem.

Comment: The problem deals with  /usr/local/etc/renderd.conf. The guide SWITCH2OSM gives you a specific path to place in the variable plug_in. Obviously plug_in contains the path to mapnik plugins needed to start the server. I used the find command to search for *mapnik* to find the directory the plug ins where actually in. Copy that directory to the plug_in variable in renderd.conf and save. I have no idea why the paths would be different, but that was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't build mapnik from source, just install the libmapnik2.2 (libmapnik) package on ubuntu 14.04.3. It put all the input plugins to `/usr/lib/mapnik/2.2/input`, not `/usr/lib/mapnik/input`.

So, change the plugins_dir in `/usr/local/etc/renderd.conf`, and it runs well.

```conf
[mapnik]
;plugins_dir=/usr/lib/mapnik/input
plugins_dir=/usr/lib/mapnik/2.2/input
```

Answer (score 0):

to find your mapnik plugins dir type the command

> mapnik-config --input-plugins

Then copy the result (plugin path) and paste in renderd.conf file

Answer (score -1):

if you have used 14.04 then mapnik path is

```
[mapnik]
plugins_dir=/usr/local/lib/mapnik/input
```